# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' when i try to split a row from csv file

Tags: python, csv, split, nltk, stop-words

I have a csv file with 10 rows of text in one column. For each row, i would like to remove the stopwords and get back the same csv file just minus the stopwords.

This is my code:

```
def remove_stopwords(filename):
  new_text_list=[]
  cr = csv.reader(open(filename,"rU").readlines()[1:])
  cachedStopWords = stopwords.words("english")

  for row in cr:
    text = ' '.join([word for word in row.split() if word not in cachedStopWords])
    print text
    new_text_list.append(text)
```

However i keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

So it seems that rows in my csv file cannot be split using .split because they are a list. How can i get around this?

Here is how my csv file looks like

```
Text

I am very pleased with the your software for contractors. It is tailored quite neatly for the construction industry.

We have two different companies, one is real estate management and one is health and nutrition services. It works great for both.
```

So the above example is the first 3 lines of my csv file. 
When i run this line of code:

```
cr = csv.reader(open(filename,"rU").readlines()[1:])
print cr[2]
```

I get this:

```
['We have two different companies, one is real estate management and one is health and nutrition services. It works great for both.']
```

Thanks,

Comment: What are the `stopwords`?

Comment: from nltk.corpus import stopwords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data file is not a CSV -- the words are separated by whitespace, not commas. So you don't need the CSV module for this. Instead, just read each line from the file and use `row = line.split()` to split the line on whitespace.

```
def remove_stopwords(filename):
    new_text_list = []
    cachedStopWords = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    with open(filename, "rU") as f:
        next(f)  # skip one line
        for line in f:
            row = line.split()
            text = ' '.join([word for word in row
                             if word not in cachedStopWords])
            print(text)
            new_text_list.append(text)
```

---

By the way, [checking membership in a `set`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is an O(1) operation, while checking membership in a `list` is an O(n) operation. So it's advantageous to make `cachedStopWords` a set:

```
cachedStopWords = set(stopwords.words("english"))
```

Comment: I tried it, the error disappeared but now its just printing the text and not removing any stopwords.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the CSV? Are you sure `csv.reader` is using the right `delimiter` (commas, by default)?

Comment: This works, thanks! I find it weird though because i saved the file as csv from excel(for mac)..what is it if its not csv? How can we check the true format?

Comment: If the excel data had only a single column, then I suppose saving it as a CSV would produce a CSV which might look like a normal text file. But that is just a guess, I'm not very familiar with excel. (I'm assuming excel would place a comma only *between* columns.) However, your third line contains a comma, so a proper CSV would have had to quote the entire line. I don't see any quotes, so my guess might be wrong.